# extern: command not found

Tags: c, environment-variables, extern

I'm following along with [this lab](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_16.04/PDF/Environment_Variable_and_SetUID.pdf) from a Udemy course on computer security which primarily uses C (I think) scripts for demonstrations. After trying to run the following program on my own computer (in both an Ubuntu and MacOS environment), I get so many errors that it seems as if the compiler doesn't even know what language it's reading.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **environ;

void printenv()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (environ[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

void main()
{
  pid_t childPid;
  switch(childPid = fork()) {
    case 0: /* child process */
      printenv();
      exit(0);
    default: /* parent process */
      //printenv();
      exit(0);
  }
}
```

The errors:

> line 4: extern: command not found 
>   line 5: syntax error near unexpected token '(' 
>   line 5: 'void printenv()'

Does anyone know what's going on? I'm unfamiliar with C (mostly work in Javascript and Python), but it seems like everything is pretty standard syntax and shouldn't be erroring.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to execute the C source code when you need to compile it first. Did you compile it?

Comment: " run the following program" How exactly? If you give details then we can on the one hand tell whether Retired Ninja might guess correctly and otherwise find whatever other problem you might be having. C programmers expect you to answer something like `gcc mycodefile.c` and then `a`. If you do something like `call mycodefile.c` (sorry, windows affliction here) then it is along Retired Ninjas guess. (And you would not be the first to have that misunderstanding, don't worry.)

Comment: Side note: [`main` should return an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/4581301)

Comment: regarding: `default: /* parent process */
      //printenv();
      exit(0);`  the parent MUST wait for the child to exit.  Otherwise, effectively, the chlld becomes a zombie. (note in modern linux OS, it is actually attached, as a child, to the `init` process.  Suggest `#include <sys/wait.h>` and in the parent, before the call to `exit()` `wait( childPid );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. does not try to produce a zombie

Note: I compiled this, on linux with:

```
gcc   -O1  -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic   -c "untitled2.c"  -I.
```

Note: I linked it with:

```
gcc   -ggdb -Wall -o "untitled2" "untitled2.o"
```

However, `fork()` can fail, in which case it returns -1, so the code should have a

```
case -1:
    perror( "fork failed" );
    break;
```

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **environ;

void printenv()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (environ[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  pid_t childPid;

  switch(childPid = fork()) 
  {
    case 0: /* child process */
      printenv();
      exit(0);

    default: /* parent process */
      //printenv();
      waitpid( childPid, NULL, 0);
      exit(0);
  }
}
```